# Arch linux soft shutdown

Tags: archlinux

I have rPi B+ with 8GB microsd card with Arch linux installed on one partition. The second partition is used for saving measurements files. The partition is FAT32. How do I upgrade reboot command for soft shutdown - sync filesystems, unmount them and then perform shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard shutdown command will do this for you

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

or

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

for a 'r'eboot rather than a 'h'alt

Comment: Lol, i've totaly forgot of this command, I thought arch linux does not have it. However, I know it from ubuntu and thanks for the guide.

Comment: And everyhthing ok, but how do I kill custom app at shutdown? I want to send it SIGTERM signal. It is java app we are talking about.

Comment: and shutdown doesn't send the right signal to your java app?
"All processes are first notified that the system is going  down by the signal SIGTERM" http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?shutdown+8